# Spring @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I keep seeing this kind of param `value = "/redirect/{id}"` in a `@RequestMapping` annotation of the Spring. I keep wondering what is `{id}` here? Is this some sort of `Expression Language`?

Sample code of what I have seen:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/files/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public void getFile( @PathVariable( "id" )
String fileName, HttpServletResponse response )
{
    try
    {
         // get your file as InputStream
         InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/pathToFile/"+ fileName);
         // copy it to response's OutputStream
         IOUtils.copy( is, response.getOutputStream() );
         response.flushBuffer();
    }
    catch( IOException ex )
    {
         throw new RuntimeException( "IOError writing file to output stream" );
    }

}
```

My question is what is the `{id}` in the mapping and what is its relationship with the `@PathVariable` annotation and how to use it? I red some info from the web but I will much more appreciate it to hear much more clearer explanation from you guys.

Comment: would be nice to close `is` in `finally` block

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `{foo}` part in a `@RequestMapping` value is a path variable which means a value retrieved from the url path and not from a request parameter.

For example if the user access to `/files/foo.zip`, then `{id}` will match `foo.zip` and you tell Spring to store that value into the variable that has the annotation `@PathVariable("id")`.

You can have multiple path variable in a URL identifier of a `@RequestMapping` annotation value, and you can inject these values into a variables by using `@PathVariable` with the same id you used inside the curly brackets.

Comment: how about `/file/x=y` does the annotation will save `x`?

Comment: No, if you want `x=y` you need to pass it like `/file/?x=y` and use a `@RequestParam("x") String x` that will correctly hold the value `y`

Answer (score 0):

I think for your example , by browsing ../files/1 or ../files/2 or ../files/3 , the digits stand for different file name . @PathVariable( "id" ) helps you save time write different parameter function on one purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The {id} is the url query string we are passing what ever it may be and retrieving that id with @PathVariable("id") and passing as a argument to the method,one method fits for different requests with changing id here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/files/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public void getFile( @PathVariable( "id" ) **String id**)
String fileName, HttpServletResponse response )
{
    //your code here
}
```

pathvariable maps your uri with the method parameter. Here id is what you send with your request eg. /files/7.