# how to go to another page with data

Tags: jquery, spring, rest, model-view-controller

I want to go with an object to another page and show it there

ViewControllers

```
    @Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/songs")
                .setViewName("/song.html");
        registry.addViewController("/")
                .setViewName("/index.html");
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/songs")
public class SongController {
@RequestMapping("/getSong")
public Track getSong(String id){
    System.out.println("Song id " + id);
    Optional<Track> byId = trackService.findById(Integer.parseInt(id));
    if(!byId.isPresent()) throw new NullPointerException();
    return byId.get();
}
```

and JQuery

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/songs/getSong",
            data: {
                id: songId
            }
        });
```

it calls method but i dont go to another page)
what should i do to reach another page with this object or with id
without using jsp or thymeleaf?

Comment: If you want to transfer to another page with the result of a request, do not use ajax.  The primary point of using ajax is to avoid a page transfer.  Use a normal form submit.

Comment: ['code'](window.location = "/song?id="+songId;) i have tryed like this, it does hange page but i couldnt get id, it was null(

Comment: That might could work, given that your endpoint mapping doesn't show that it must be a POST request.  The if songId is null, then you have another issue related to that, which is not identifiable with the logic you have provided so far.

Comment: it was null only in controllers method, in brouser it was a number. @Taplar it must be a POST request Result the same with GET

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627961/spring-requestmapping  You have to configure where the parameter is coming from for the request mapping

Comment: i know) i did like this  @RequestMapping("/getSong{id}")
    public Track getSong(@PathVariable("id") String id)'

Comment: `@RequestMapping("/getSong{id}") ` does not match `/song?id=` you said you tried with the window.location

Comment: should it be like this `@RequestMapping("/getSong/{id}")`?

Comment: It has to match whatever pattern you are putting in the url.  Make it match exactly the same, putting `{id}` where ever the variable is in the url

Comment: `window.location = "/songs/getSong"+songId; `got it) ty) but i didnt get how it works (not about url or method. i just get an emty page with json and dont know what to do with it)

Comment: I mean is there is a way to do it like when you return ModelAndView ?

Comment: You're getting into spring territory there.  I'll have to direct you towards other users who are using spring more frequently.  Sadly I haven't done spring in a few years.

Comment: @taplar i did it this way  `$('#songs').on("click", function (event) {
            window.location = "/song?id="+$(event.target).closest('tr').attr('id');
        });` and on song page `var songId = $.urlParam('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/songs/getById",
        data: {
            id: songId
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#songTitle").text(response.title);
        }
    });` is it looks weird?