# I am getting a 404 Error on API Call in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

I am working on a Spring Boot Application. I am getting a **404 error** on hitting the URL-path which I have configured. Where am I going wrong?

**HomeController.java**

```
package com.example.homes;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController("/add")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String add() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

**HomeApplication.java**

```
package com.example.homes;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HomeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HomeApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Inside main");
    }

}
```

Comment: Explain us what you do before you get 404.

Comment: show how you start your service, and how you make the call to it

Comment: http://localhost:8080/add/hello

Comment: Aren't you missing servlet context path?

Comment: Can you see ***Inside main*** in your console logs?

Comment: When Spring starts up, it should print out a good amount of information to the console. There should be a line that reads something like: `: Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''`. Can you locate the information for your app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing RequestMapping for `/add`. You kept as `@RestController` property. It should be `@RequestMapping("/add")`. In your current code `hello` is mapped to root.

try  `localhost:8080/hello` and it will work.

If you want`localhost:8080/add/hello`

Then it should be like below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/add")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/hello") 
    public String add() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

***[@RestController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56882597/10961238)*** is a specialized version of `@Controller` which adds `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotation automatically. so we do not have to add `@ResponseBody` to our mapping methods.

***[@RequestMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627961/spring-requestmapping)*** maps HTTP requests to handler methods of MVC and REST controllers.

Here possible suspect is `@RestController("/add")` which should be `@RequestMapping("/add")`

**@RequestMapping at Class Level**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/add")
public class HomeController {

    //localhost:8080/add/hello (No Context Path in application.properties)
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String add() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

**@RequestMapping at Method Level**

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    //localhost:8080/hello (No Context Path in application.properties)
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String add() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

If you don't have any context path defined in `application.properties` then calling
`localhost:8080/add/hello` will give the desired output

In case you have a context path as *app* then call `localhost:8080/app/add/hello`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing `@RestController("/add")`, Do this,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/add")
```

Then you should be able to call `localhost:8080/<ApplicationContext>/add/hello`